# set up iCloud Family Sharing

Tags: macos, iphone, family-sharing

I am trying to set up iCloud Family Sharing. I have tried on OS X, iPhone and iPad.

In Settings/iCloud/Manage Family I click on the "+" button (which is greyed) although a pop up balloon says "Add family member" but nothing happens.

---

I have 2 accounts.

System Preferences/Internet Accounts shows an iCloud account which I use to synch my files to my other devices.
This is shown as my primary account.

Internet Accounts also shows an iCloud account as "inactive". This is my original Apple ID which I use for software purchases, and is the account I want to share.

System Preferences/iCloud shows my primary (personal sharing) account.

When I click on Family Sharing this shows me as the organiser at the email of the Apple ID and shows Family Purchases and my credit card.
This shows me as Parent (with my primary account email).

Comment: are the family members on the same network?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes they are

Comment: Are you signed into the principle account?